# How to save excel file as a csv file while retaining indentation of the file?

Tags: excel, csv, indentation

I have an excel file with indentation as follow.

```
A
 B
```

I am using column one, row one and two.
 When I Save the file as a csv file it remove the indentation.
How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Indentation is a format and CSVx do not retain formats.  You will need to use actual spaces to move the data over in the cell.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if it is possible to replace indentation to black spaces, without manually having to do it?

Comment: That would require vba.